Understanding HIGH_NUMBER_OF_BYTES_USED in mysql performance schema
On analyzing a MySQL database I found the following which does not match my interpretation of the documentation.
According to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-perfschema-excerpt/8.0/en/performance-schema-memory-summary-tables.html the value HIGH_NUMBER_OF_BYTES_USED is the peak value of CURRENT_NUMBER_OF_BYTES_USED.

HIGH_NUMBER_OF_BYTES_USED are higher estimates. The value reported by the Performance Schema is guaranteed to be greater than or equal to the highest count or size of memory effectively used at runtime.

I am using a query like this:
SELECT 
  event_name,
  CURRENT_NUMBER_OF_BYTES_USED,
  HIGH_NUMBER_OF_BYTES_USED
FROM performance_schema.memory_summary_by_user_by_event_name 
ORDER BY HIGH_NUMBER_OF_BYTES_USED DESC;




event_name
CURRENT_NUMBER_OF_BYTES_USED
HIGH_NUMBER_OF_BYTES_USED




memory/innodb/memory
0
4683340148216


memory/innodb/ut0rbt
0
1645730488655


memory/innodb/memory
0
1313629249552


memory/innodb/memory
69617648
566959468240


memory/innodb/memory
55235800
550238428888


memory/innodb/memory
35059688
535101215776


memory/mysqld_openssl/openssl_malloc
319248
500309476016


memory/innodb/memory
52407992
466328605280


memory/temptable/physical_ram
0
401940983744


memory/innodb/memory
13170288
366240805960


memory/innodb/memory
0
320503119064


memory/innodb/ut0rbt
1174538
204114244954


memory/innodb/ut0rbt
0
196414978880


memory/innodb/ut0rbt
629330
194865010019


memory/innodb/memory
0
187385710296


memory/innodb/ut0rbt
206
161442642667


memory/innodb/ut0rbt
3193
137133433237


memory/innodb/ut0rbt
0
135418217052


memory/innodb/ut0rbt
0
132751731201


memory/sql/String::value
99168
82918779736


memory/innodb/memory
0
79710777216


memory/sql/String::value
2518677440
76768637976


memory/sql/Filesort_buffer::sort_keys
0
66049513286


memory/innodb/ut0rbt
0
64399985070


memory/innodb/memory
0
60209901392


memory/temptable/physical_ram
4194432
50148801152


...
...
...



In the result, I get a value of HIGH_NUMBER_OF_BYTES_USED which seems to be above 4TB, which is much more, than the machine has as physical memory (100GB) and what is reported in the metrics as maximum ram usage.
On the other side, using the table memory_summary_by_thread_by_event_name, the values seem fine, though some events seem to share memory across threads, because the current usage would not match the sum of the threads.
Further in the documentation:

Thread 1 uses memory in the range from 1MB to 2MB during execution, as reported by the LOW_NUMBER_OF_BYTES_USED and HIGH_NUMBER_OF_BYTES_USED columns of the memory_summary_by_thread_by_event_name table.
Thread 2 uses memory in the range from 10MB to 12MB during execution, as reported likewise.
When these two threads belong to the same user account, the
per-account summary estimates that this account used memory in the
range from 11MB to 14MB. That is, the LOW_NUMBER_OF_BYTES_USED for the
higher level aggregate is the sum of each LOW_NUMBER_OF_BYTES_USED
(assuming the worst case). Likewise, the HIGH_NUMBER_OF_BYTES_USED for
the higher level aggregate is the sum of each
HIGH_NUMBER_OF_BYTES_USED (assuming the worst case).
11MB is a lower estimate that can occur only if both threads hit the
low usage mark at the same time.
14MB is a higher estimate that can occur only if both threads hit the
high usage mark at the same time.

This explains some summarization, but not the exceeding of physical memory. Checking the LOW_NUMBER_OF_BYTES_USED shows values of 0 or low negative numbers, on threads always 0.
Is there an explanation for the high reported usage of RAM on tables like memory_summary_by_user_by_event_name or memory_summary_global_by_event_name? Is shared memory summed up or is there allocated RAM, which is not used in physical RAM? Or is there a misconfiguration of the MySQL-Server (MySQL8.0.35-27.1, virtual machine on ubuntu 20.04 LTS)?

What exact version are you using? Query SELECT VERSION();. A similar case was reported as a bug against 8.0.29, and it was claimed to have been fixed in 8.0.30. See https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=108288

Fetch the column USER, too.

I've added the exact version with 8.0.35-27.1 but it is above 8.0.30. Concerning the username, as part of the credentials, I did not wanted to give the real usernames. I could replace the names, if there is a value on having them? With memory/sql/String::value it is the user root, everything else are different usernames for each repeated event.
